# How do I control another Android application in Android Studio (Java)?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I currently know how to open another Android app using Android Studio:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.otherApp.stuff");
if (launchIntent != null) {
  startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

However, once the other app is opened, how do I actually have my Android Studio app click buttons within the other app? For reference, I do not own the other app (so I don't have any source code for it).

Comment: "how do I actually have my Android Studio app click buttons within the other app?" -- generally speaking, that is not an option. If you are doing this for legitimate accessibility reasons, look at the accessibility APIs.